# Feeds import by http always imports even after deleting the source

Tags: caching, feeds

I'm using Feeds to import an xml file. I'm using cron to do this every minute. I noticed that if I delete the source file, the import still succeds! It seems Feeds caches the data somewhere and there is no setting to disable this as far as I know.

This would not be a problem because I don't allow to have duplicate content but I need to have a different file with the same name to get different data but Feeds, recognizing a file with the same name, ignores it and imports the cached data.

Does anyone knows a good solution to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

EDIT: I can't find any temp file in the system but in the db there is a '`cache_feeds_http`' table that has in fact the data from the file. I tried truncate the table and delete the source file but the behaviour is still the same. What's going on here?!?! Where is the data being pulled?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem changing FeedsHTTPFetcher to FeedsFileFetcher in my module and changing the importers to file also. In this case, each import gets the file even if there's already one with the same name.